# thunderbird - show images from localhost

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a local mail server which I use to receive emails sent from my web application on my development environment.

In these emails I have images which comes from `localhost` domain, e.g.

```
<img style="display:block;" src="https://localhost:448/online/static/images/logoEmail.png" alt="Logo" border="0" alt="" />
```

When I open these emails with Thunderbird I do not see the image, but instead I see only the `alt` text.

I have double-checked the image URL and it's correct. If I try to open the image from my browser I can see it.

On Thunderbird I have checked the option to allow remote content in email messages for all domains and all senders, but still I can't see images coming from `localhost`.

Is there a way to see images from `localhost` on Thunderbird?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive this is an issue but it is worth a check: does Thunderbird trust the TLS certificate served by your computer? Thunderbird uses a different certificate authority (CA) store than the OS generally and so even if browsers don't display a TLS warning with your localhost's TLS certificate Thunderbird may block loading the content because it has a TLS error.

To fix this add and trust your localhost's CA (or cert if self-signed) in Thunderbird's certificate store by going to **Settings, Privacy & Security, Manage Certificates... button, Authorities tab & Import... button** for CA and then '**Edit Trust...**' button to ensure that the CA is trusted to **identify web sites**. For a self-signed cert you may have to use the Servers tab and 'Add Exception...'.